# PC waking up randomly

Tags: windows-7, sleep

My PC wakes up randomly after I put it to sleep, in different periods of time (typically after a few minutes). I've tried to disable all possible wake up reasons, but to no avail.

```
D:\>powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Wake Timer
    Owner: [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (wuauserv)

D:\>powercfg -waketimers
There are no active wake timers in the system.

D:\>powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
HID Keyboard Device
HID Keyboard Device (002)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

UPD explanation for paladins of purity: I've tried all usual ways of solving this problem and none helped. And it *doesn't* happen on schedule.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help me find the offending process waking my Windows 7 PC from hibernate every night](http://superuser.com/questions/103380/help-me-find-the-offending-process-waking-my-windows-7-pc-from-hibernate-every-n)

Comment: @DavidPostill, it's not.

Comment: If you set windows Update to Manual Install does it still wakeup?  From your question `wuauserv` is Windows Update Service.

Comment: @albal, it didn't help. The last wake reason is still the same.

Comment: @user626528 did you reboot for that change to be effective?

Comment: @albal, it seems this have solved the problem. It's strange, because the option to wake up for updates installation was turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last wakeup event is for `wuauserv` which is the Windows Update Service.  If Windows Update is set to Manual rather than a specific time of the day then this should prevent Windows Update Service from waking the machine.

Comment: It's strange, because the option to wake up for updates installation was turned off. Switching settings to "Choose what updates to install" solves this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: `powercfg -lastwake: wuauserv`

maybe something to do with error 0x80070057 in windowsUpdate.log.>> ou yes, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6eHDtylDYo this will fix, the first steps at least, remowing some files from folders. at least didnt not wake up, after waiting

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue for a few months now.  I was able to resolve it by installing a Microsoft hotfix which is the latest update to the System Update Readiness Tool.  See the following KB:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821

Since installing the SURT update yesterday, there have been NO errors in Windowsupdate.log, and the PC has not woken up by itself once!